# Do powershell modules load automatically when opening the SharePoint 2010 command shell?

Tags: powershell

I have a custom module and want to load it in the command shell without having to call it explicitly each time I delve into Powershell.

Does it load automatically?

If not, how can I make it load automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From PowerShell, evaluate the variable:

```
$profile
```

Verify that the directory specified in $profile exists, create the file if necessary (note: The directory and file are created by the user. Until you do so the first time neither the directory nor file will exist). Edit file specified by $profile in your favorite text editor. At the end of the profile add the line:

```
import-module <path-to-module>
```

If you use custom nouns/verbs and you want to avoid the noisy warnings just add the flag "-DisableNameChecking" to your import module call.

```
import-module <path-to-module> -DisableNameChecking
```

Now, reload your shell.

If you'd like to 'publish' your module so that you can import the module by name rather than by path then make a directory for your module under one of the directories in "$env:psmodulepath" (the one under windows is a system wide module repository) and copy your module file(s) there. Once you've done that you can import your module by name instead of by path.

```
import-module <name-of-module>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to do two things

1. Add you module to your Documents folder (Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

1. Modify your profile file (Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profile.ps1) to have the include

eg Import-Module Pscx

And if that doesnt work try adding your import to:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\sharepoint.ps1

Thats the file the sharepoint powershell console imports

Comment: Editing the SharePoint.ps1 file stops my console from loading correctly so I suggest people don't try doing that.

Comment: Also, there's no Profile.ps1 in the location suggested (although the Interweb suggests there should be). Just to clarify I'm on a Win2008R2 server rather than Win7.